# TSQL Why is Top faster with a variable?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Morning all,

I have been working on some moderately complex sql to 'obtain' some data from a third party products database, to display it in our own in house applications.

I added in a select to obtain the top record from a table within a subquery (if thats makes sense)

the query took nearly 3minutes to return a final result set of 100 records using

```
SELECT TOP 1 ...
```

I had a look online for improvements to what I was trying to achieve and it was suggested that I change my select to use a variable, as below

```
DECLARE @topCount INT
SET @topCount = 1

SELECT TOP (@topCount) ...
```

This took the same query from the 3minutes down to 1second, which is great!

But can anyone explain why this is so.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you do `top 1` the query optimizer will build a plan that is built to fetch 1 row as fast as possible.

When you use a local variable the value of the variable is unknown to the optimizer and instead builds a plan that is optimized to fetch 100 rows as fast as possible.

In your case the query plan generated with a row goal of 100 is the better plan to use even when you only want one row.

To verify you can try to add `option (recompile)` to your query with the variable. In that case SQL Server will use the current value of `@topCount` as a row goal and since that is 1 you should get the slow plan.

Comment: I understand the difference in plan, but it amazes me that fetching 1 row can be slower than fetching 100 rows.  I would think that if the 100-row plan works best, SQL Server would use the same plan for `top 1`.

Comment: @Brandon it does not fetch 100 rows, only builds the execution plan with the assumption that 100 rows is what is wanted. The execution terminates when 1 row is found.

Comment: Checking what's different with execution plan in these cases probably would help to understand what the issue is with top 1.

Comment: this does not make sense at all. If with `SELECT TOP 1`, it will build the best plan for `TOP 1` then it must be the fastest query at first (but it takes 3 minutes?). For a general plan (not specific to any value) by using `SELECT TOP` with a ***local variable***, it then can run `SELECT TOP 1` (with value of 1 passed in for the variable) so quickly. That means it is even better than the *best* plan?. Also if using a variable made it behave the way you explained, there shouldn't have had any difference between ***local variable*** and ***parameter*** (such as passed via `sp_executesql`).

Comment: @Hopeless local variables and parameters are not treated the same by the query optimizer. Values for parameters is used by the optimizer when creating a query plan but the values for local variables is not used and instead is optimized as unknown.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson what you said can just explain the second part, what about the first part in my comment before?

Comment: @Hopeless I guess you are referring to this part "In your case the query plan generated with a row goal of 100 is the better plan to use even when you only want one row.".
That can be explained by the fact that SQL Server really tries hard to build the best plan possible but sometimes she just falls short. With specific examples of queries that behaves like that it is usually possible to figure out why SQL Server went the wrong way and what she needs to be able to do a better job.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson I was referring to the first part in my first comment here. However, what you said later does make sense a bit but to me SQL Server simply fails, and this should be considered as a bug. `SELECT TOP 1` should pick the best plan and should run fastest because it has all the info it needs. In the other case, the `TOP` value is put in a local variable and suppose it's unclear, SQL Server may pick a very general plan and may perform worse. That's what making sense to me.